# How to get access to parent id in subquery?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to run subquery for every id_product from parent query (id_product).

```
SELECT 
    id_product,     
    (SELECT SUM(total_quantity)
     FROM 
         (SELECT sh.date, SUM(cp.quantity) AS total_quantity
          FROM ps1769_xcustom_stock_history sh
          LEFT JOIN ps1769_cart_product cp ON (cp.id_product = sh.id AND DATE(cp.date_add) = sh.date)
          WHERE sh.date <= '2023-10-10'
            AND sh.quantity > 0
            AND sh.id =  ???
          GROUP BY sh.date
          ORDER BY sh.date DESC
          LIMIT 30) AS subquery
    ) AS AVG30
FROM
    ps1769_product p
```

I tried `sh.id = p.id_product` but this parameter is unavailable in subquery.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: it should be fine to write `sh.id = p.id`, are you getting an error from execution?

Comment: Yes, in tab  ps1769_product there is id_product not only id, so I tried  `sh.id = p.id_product` but I get "Unknown column 'p.id_product' in where clause"

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126339/subquery-cant-find-column-from-superquerys-join

Comment: You cannot transfer external columns through nesting level. Use CTE.

Comment: Subqueries can only access columns from their parent query `1` level higher. This subquery is `2` levels deeper than `p.id_product`.

Comment: Your query with `sh.id = p.id_product` would work on MySQL 8, so I guess that means you are stuck on 5.7 (now dead)? You will probably need to use user variables for row counting and group tracking to achieve the [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+greatest-n-per-group).